# CSS grid - the height of items in one column are affecting the layout in another column

Tags: css, grid, tailwind-css

I have an accordion that uses Tailwind CSS.

The accordion has an equal width, but the height of the open accordion on the right is affecting the position of the one on the left.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpf8x.png)

Here's the code:

```html
<div className="w-full lg:w-10/12 grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-4 mx-auto">
  <div>
    /* item one on the left */
    <Accordion className="rounded-3xl shadow-2xl bg-rb-light-200">
      <AccordionSummary>
        <span className="text-primary text-left font-semibold text-2xl">
          The question
        </span>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails className=" w-11/12 text-xl text-left text-rb-dark-100">
        <span>The answer</span>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  </div>
  <div>
    /* item two on the right */
    <Accordion className="rounded-3xl shadow-2xl bg-rb-light-200">
      <AccordionSummary>
        <span className="text-primary text-left font-semibold text-2xl">
          The question
        </span>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails className=" w-11/12 text-xl text-left text-rb-dark-100">
        <span>The answer</span>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can span the `grid-row` of “item 2 on the right” by 2? I don’t have experience with tailwind-css, but for the basic css you can do `div:nth-child(2) { grid-row: 1 / span 2; }`

Comment: I quickly lookup the tailwind-css doc, it seems you can archive what I did in previous comment by `<div class=“row-span-2”> // your item two on right` I suggest to span this element because it is visually twice as big as your other two elements from your pic.

Comment: Thank you @jimmymcheung for the response. Please note that the FAQ are not static. I'm currently fetching them from an array of lists. so I use the `div:nth-child(2)` I guess it won't work for other div items on the right if the questions are like 4 or more.

What do you think?

Comment: is grid-auto-flow:column usable in your case?

Comment: @pierfarrugia that works. However, its now affecting my overall style. The grid items are not obeying the col-2 I set for large screens. Everything now tries to sit in a straight row instead of a column of two.

Comment: @youngP no `div:nth-child(2)` applies only to the second child element (no matter how much element you have) of your grid, which in the current case is the only item at the right. I like to always try my best to support JS-banned browser, but if that's not your concern, you could try using js to get the height of the element and add `grid-row: span n` (or `row-span-n` for tailwind). if you always have larger element at the right (and in the HTML it is always the even elements) you can use `nth-child(even)`

Comment: @youngP if `grid-auto-flow: column` works for you, you need to define `grid-template-row` instead of column, if you don't care much of the order of the placement, you can use `grid-template-row: repeat(2, min-content);` replace `2` to (n elements / 2) so you can maintain 2 items per row (≈2 column). Use media query so this only applies to large screen.

Comment: Thank you all for the support. What would I have done with you?

Gracious.